# Pass value from aspx to event handler in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I asked this question in the msdn forums, and aside from one person, who suggested what was actually a work-around, everybody was stumped.

---

In my Webforms project, I have some aspx code that looks like the following:

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %>
<%{ %>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler" />
<%} %>
```

The code successfully renders 10 buttons that say `"Click Here"`

---

What I want to do, is make an event handler for clicking on the button that takes `i` as a parameter.

```
    protected void MyButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something with i
    }
```

---

Regarding the project I was working on when I first asked this question at msdn, I ended up doing something completely different, but still, If there is a way to do what I'm trying to do, I would very much like to know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this thread proves, it isn't trivial to place the value of a variable, like i, into a server control directly  from markup.  As Joe correctly pointed out, code render blocks (<%=i %>) don't work within server controls.  The <%=i %> syntax would work great in an html tag, but server controls, like your button, don't support it.

I'd recommend moving the control flow from markup into codebehind by using a repeater.  That will allow you to set the command arguments from code behind.  This is far more inline with how asp.net works.  So ...

```
    <%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %>
    <%{ %>
      <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler" />
    <%} %>
```

would become something more like

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="ButtonRepeater" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="ButtonRepeater_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button id="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

You can of course still add all the html that you want in the ItemTemplate tags.  Then in the code behind add the following.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ButtonRepeater.DataSource = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // however many items you want
        this.ButtonRepeater.DataBind();
    }

    protected void MyButtonHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        if (b != null)
        {
            string cmdName = b.CommandName;
            // logic based on cmdName
        }
    }

    protected void ButtonRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = e.Item.FindControl("MyButton") as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            var buttonNumber = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
            button.CommandName = buttonNumber;
            button.ID = string.Format("MyButton_{0}", buttonNumber); // required to prevent event validation error
        }
    }
```

I actually tested this out by putting a breakpoint in the event handler over the cmdName variable.  It was being set appropriately based on the button that I clicked.

This is a paradigm shift, but it is a shift that is inline with the intent of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [a code-render block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) (i.e. `<% =inline-expression %>`) to set properties of Web server controls such as `<asp:Button>`.

This syntax is mostly a hangover from classic ASP, and if when you first had this problem, you

> ... ended up doing something completely different

then you did the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the simple JavaScript

1. Create hidden field

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="myButtonValue" id="myButtonValue" />
   ```
2. Assign onclick event to button

   ```
   <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler" OnClientClick="setValue(<%= i %>" />
   ```
3. Create JavaScript function

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function setValue(val)
   {
       document.getElementById('myButtonValue').value = val;
   }
   </script>
   ```

   Then use your variable in code

   ```
   protected void MyButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       int i = 0;
       int.TryParse(Request.Form["myButtonValue"].ToString(), out i);
       //do somethign with i
   }
   ```

Comment: where does myButtonValue get set? when i tried to run the code, it was empty

Answer (score 0):

The most stable method that I can think of would be to have (inside of your for loop) a panel(placeholder, you get the idea), and inside of that panel have both your button as well as an ASP:Hidden control or a hidden label with `i` as the value.
In the button click event you can cast `sender` to be a button, grab the parent (panel) control of that, and then get the hidden child control.

Comment: okay, How to i make a hidden control that has i as the value?  the whole reason why I'm unable to do this is because I can't really use i as any meaningful attribute in the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **CommandName** property to distinguish the buttons:

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %>
<%{ %>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler" CommandName='cmd<%= i.ToString() %>'/>
<%} %>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
protected void MyButtonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    if (b != Null)
    {
       string cmdName = b.CommandName;
       // logic based on cmdName
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't quite work as expected.  I've posted an edit in my question

Comment: @SamIam Are you saying that CommandName doesn't return i's value?

Comment: @nuux I'm saying that it DIDN'T return i's value.

Comment: Your CommandArgument attribute does not have quotes around the value.  if find if you want to use code in the attribute value many times single quotes are necessary (not sure why) - so try CommandArgument='<%= i.ToString %>' or CommandArgument='<% i.ToString %>'

Comment: @mjmarsh ozhug's example was the one that used CommandArguement, yours used CommandName, and it did include single quotes

Comment: No luck, it doesn't render the value

Answer (score 0):

You could use the a command button and the 
Button.Command Event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx

you would end up with something like this. (i have not tested code below)

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %> 
<%{ %> 
 <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" 
               CommandName="something"
               CommandArgument=<%=i%> 
               onCommand="MyButtonHandler"  /> 
<%} %> 

void myButtonHandler(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
     i = (int)e.CommandArgument;
     //do something with i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it; the event handlers you see on controls are baked into the asp.net framework - there is server and client side support for them - the framework emits all of the necessary wiring to tie a server side control, it's HTML equivalent, and all of the events together. You can't simply just change these signatures without reworking a lot of parts.

However, what you can do is define custom event args; if you derive your own control, then you can implement your own event handler with your [own custom event args that inherit from System.EventArgs](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=42)

There are several other alternatives:

[Client Callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx).

[OnCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx)

Comment: I've looked into your suggestion, and I've began working on that, but if I did actually create a custom control, how would I actually get the variable `i` in the custom event args?

Comment: There's lots of different ways. You've already explored the easiest with OnCommand but some people also just use button and name their buttons consistently - for example MyButton_1, MyButton_2 and then strip this off server side to leave 1, 2 etc. The way to do it with custom controls is, when the control is created to use something like a hidden field (a similar usage is already discussed on this page) or go the whole hog and store your new control's property in ViewState by implementing IPostBackDataHandler. When the post back happens, your code pulls the property out of the viewstate.

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert in ASP but you can try a similar approach

```
<%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) %>
<%{ 
 // build the below string in ASP. Make the event handler MyubttonHanlder1,
 // MyButtonHanlder2, ... and so on, then echo it using response.Write. It  
 // will create 10 control each with its own handler. Create 10 handlers 
 // on the back end.

    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButtonHandler"+i />
}%>
```

Comment: that gives me a parser error.  it says that the tag is not well formed

Comment: I mean I don't know ASP that well, so you will have to fix it. It is just the approach that I wanted to convey.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter: ASP != ASP.NET. I think that's the crux of this only theoretical  question. Even if it would work, the inline approach is simply not what was intended with ASP.NET.